# How to get a List from string from List of Map with Java 8 Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have list of hash maps and I am looking for list of UserId.

Data like:

```
[
 {UserId=10033, name=Siegmund},
 {UserId=10034, name=Sied},
 {UserId=10035, name=mund}
]
```

I am trying like:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> result = 
    (List<HashMap<String, Object>>) resultMap.get("resultList");
result.forEach(mapObj -> {
    System.out.println(mapObj.get("UserId"));
});
```

But looking for some better solution for this.
Thanks

Comment: why do you even have a `List<HashMap<String, Object>> ` instead of `Map<UserId, String>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull all `name` values into a single list using something like this:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = ...;
List<Integer> userIds = list.stream()
                        .map(map -> (Integer) map.get("UserId"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

From your data , you can have Map , why list of Maps.
You can try something like below

```
Map<String,String> listMap = new HashMap<>();
        listMap.put("10033","Siegmund");
        listMap.put("10034","Sied");
        listMap.put("10035","mund");

        List<String> userIDList = listMap.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());

        userIDList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

or if you really need to parse through list of Maps then you can do as below

```
List<String> userIDList = listOfMaps.stream().map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Collection::stream).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());

        userIDList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```